# Script from excel to notepad

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, scripting

I have a question about scripts writing. 
I need to export data from excel to certain places in notepad. 
**For example**:
I have a thousand rows with 4 columns A,B,C,D which contains class, attribute, word, word English translation. I need that it would be exported to notepad like this:

```
    (Language, column A value, column B value, column C value).
    (English, column A value, column B value, column D value).
later same with the second row and so on...
```

Maybe you have some advice? Or should I do this with VB macro?

Comment: Have you considered simply saving your file as a comma separated values (.csv) file?  This will do all you are asking and without the need for anything outside of native Excel functionality...  You can then open the file in Notepad (or Excel) as you like.

Comment: But I need to mix of columns. From one row I need to make 2rows in text file, one with value C and other with value D, also add static value for every text row.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Can you edit your question to show examples of the input as well as the desired output?

Comment: What language? VBA and VB.NET are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're getting at. I'd do it in a VB macro. There are numerous ways of doing this, but I think I'd chug through the list with something like the code below (based on your stated desired output), and then save Sheet2 as a csv file:

```
Sub Filemaker()

    ' Start on top of Sheet1 - I'm assuming you have a blank Sheet2 at the ready in the same workbook
    Range("A1").Select

    Do
    ValueA = ActiveCell
    ValueB = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    ValueC = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
    ValueD = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)

    Sheets("Ark2").Select   ' We move over to the other sheet. Again, make sure this starts on top of the sheet
    ActiveCell = "Language" '' Start dishing out the data values:
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ValueA
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = ValueB
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = ValueC
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select '' Putting most of the same values in a row number two, am I getting this right?
    ActiveCell = "English"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ValueA
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = ValueB
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = ValueD
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select '' And then move down one more row to receive next set of values?

    ValueA = ValueB = ValueC = ValueD = Null ' Empty values before next round
    Sheets("Ark1").Select ' We move back to the first sheet, prearing to take on next row
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select '' And now we should be ready
    Loop While ActiveCell <> ""

End Sub
```